# Cannot find module 'angular' inside angular 2 project

Tags: angularjs, module, components

I'm using angular-cli, typescript, trying to downgrade angular2 component, so it will work inside angular 1.5 project but the module is not recognize. What I'm missing?

```
    // Angular 1 Vendor Import
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

Comment: can you just check name of the folder? and what if you try to call it different like angular_1

Comment: same issue with another alias

Comment: even if you do import {componentname} from 'angular_1'

Comment: I am getting 'cannot find module 'angular_1'

Comment: do you have renamed the folder in node_modules from angular to angular_1?

Comment: There is no angular folder inside node_modules

Comment: but sorry ... the folder angular from where you're tryng to import modules...where is? ..is made from you? or is the angular folder installed with npm?

Comment: My mistake, I see inside node_models a folder named @angular. Everything is installed with npm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134061/discussion-between-federico-scamuzzi-and-angularone).

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by:

```
npm install @types/angular
```